# Woocommerce - Change the Product Pages Directory from /product to /somethingelse

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Noobie question here. Is it possible to change the directory that product pages get stored in.

For example, I would like all my product pages to be stored under examplesite.com/**reviews**/ instead of examplesite.com/**product**/ which is what woocommerce (or maybe it's my theme) seems to use by default.

Any advice on how to accomplish this is much appreciated!

Comment: Go to Wordpress Settings > Permalinks > Product permalinks. Choose "custom" and add your custom path name. Then save.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec! Wow so simple...